# Corpo da application/x-www-form-urlencoded não está sendo passado parametros

Tags: php, json, libcurl, header, postman

Tenho o código abaixo que está enviando o post em formato json para uma aplicação para busca de dados:

$url='http://exemplo.com.br/url_teste.php';
$valor_token = '';

// cria um resource cURL
$ch = curl_init($url);

$data_array=array('dataIntegration' => '{"ano":"2022","sistema":"CTR"}');
$data=http_build_query($data_array);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;Token:'. $valor_token));

// agora vamos anexar o corpo em formato json da sua requisição
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $data);

// ative o recebimento de retorno da requisição
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

echo $resultado = curl_exec($ch);

// encerra conexão e libera variável
curl_close($ch);
// Verifica se ocorreu algum erro
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
echo 'Erro: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

echo '

```
'.print_r(json_decode($resultado),true).'
```

';

Não sei qual o motivo o array que está sendo passado no CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS não está sendo aceito pela aplicação. Erro informado é que não foi autorizado. Já testei os mesmos parâmetros e token no postman e funcionou normalmente, mas na aplicação PHP não funciona.

Answer (score -3):

Pode tentar da seguinte forma

```
$postFields = ['ano' => 2022, 'sistema' => 'CTR'];
$postFieldsJson = json_encode($postFields);

$ch = curl_init('http://exemplo.com.br/url_teste.php');

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postFieldsJson,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Content-Type: application/json'],
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
]);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($info);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<hr>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Outro HTTPHEADER que você pode passar é o

```
'Accept: application/json'
```

Porém teria de saber se a sua requisição é respondida também no formato JSON.